# PostgreSQL Database - How to query a table in order and sequentially (infinite scroll)

Tags: javascript, python, sql, database, postgresql

I am not lost when dealing with databases but also not an expert.

I want to implement infinite scroll on my website, which means data needs to be in order, either by date_created or id descending. My initial thought was to use LIMIT and OFFSET in a query like this (using SQLalchemy):

```
session.query(Posts).filter(Posts.owner_id == _userid_).filter(Posts.id < post_id).orderBy(desc(Posts.id)).limit(5).all()
```

which translates to something like this:

```
SELECT * from posts WHERE owner_id = _userid_ AND id < _post_id_ ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET _somevalue_;
```

and in my js:

```
var minimum_post_id = 0;
var posts_list = [];
var post_ids = [];

function infinite_load(_userid_, _post_id_) {
  fetch('/users/' + _userid_ + '/posts/' + _post_id_)
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => { 
     console.log(data); 
     data.posts.forEach(post => { posts_list.push(post); post_ids.push(post.id) });
     minimum_post_id = Math.min(...post_ids);
   })
}

infinite_load(1, minimum_post_id) // random user id
```

However, i was researching to see if this was efficient and came across this: https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/

Basically it is saying that there limit and offset is bad because it still has to count all of the records to offset, only to throw them away.

So my question is, is my implementation inadequate? How do i efficiently query a database sequentially?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pagination -- done correctly -- has a few more barbs than a simple "What id range did we show last page?  Add 10 to limit and offset."  Some quick questions to whet your appetite, then a suggestion:

- While a user is looking at items positioned 11 through 20, a record is inserted at position 15.  What is returned to the user upon clicking the 'Next' pagination button?
- Conversely, while a user is looking at records positioned from 101 through 110, 10 arbitrarily records below are position 100 are removed.  What does the user get after a 'Next' pagination click?  Or a 'Previous' pagination click?

Depending on your data model, schema, and UI requirements, these can be simple or *really* difficult to answer.

Now, to why LIMIT/OFFSET is the wrong way to do it ... It's not, actually, provided you have a small enough dataset -- and that can be plenty large for most sites.  In other words, pick what works for *your* setup.

Meanwhile, for the pedagogically minded under the "really large" data set assumption: it's the OFFSET that is the killer part of that query (as it requires the results to be tallied, sorted, counted, then skipped before the LIMIT can kick in).  So, how can we remove the OFFSET?  Incorporate it into the CONSTRAINT section of your query.

Your query orders by ID, then offsets by some number.  Remove the offset, by ensuring that the ID is greater (or less) than what the current screen shows for the user:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE
    owner_id = _userid_
AND id < _last_displayed_id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Similarly, if you're ordering by time, then, make your pagination button (or scroll handler) request new records after/before the last item already presented to the user.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this! So if i understand correctly, offset is always applied when using a compare operator or when using the actual OFFSET keyword? i am not making raw sql queries, i am using an ORM. I don't see how the offset is being applied programmatically...

Comment: I'm not sure from the code you've posted, either.  If it's a concern, suggest looking at the raw SQL logs of your dev server.  Or get SQLAlchemy to tell you what SQL it's sending: [Printing actual SQLAlchemy queries](http://nicolascadou.com/blog/2014/01/printing-actual-sqlalchemy-queries/)

Comment: This solution is good as long as you use numeric id column. Imagine that you have guids and suddenly life is more complicated. For example, you want to implement user search feature. You don't want to expose numeric ids.

Comment: Isn't it great when you come up with a solution and then see your solution validated on an accepted SO answer whose author sounds like they know their stuff?! Thanks mate! "Similarly, if you're ordering by time, then, make your pagination button (or scroll handler) request new records after/before the last item already presented to the user"